# GAE: use static HTML file vs database to serve contents

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

My new site (to read books) actually uses static content to serve the pages: I have the HTML file saved in a folder and, to serve the page, I read it and pass the content to a jinja2 template, to show all together. No database hits except for get the book ID to know the title.

This is working fine and fast, but it is obvious that I must "upload" every new book with the "Deploy" option from GAE SDK (from what I've read, there is no way to access the file system in GAE from outside, like with an FTP), which is not the optimally way.

So I'm thinking on save the HTML contents to the database but: will this increase the database hits a lot? I'm using NDB, so in theory, every user that reads a book will get the cached result from the NDB cache, once it was readed the first time. Is this right?

Will be better to pass the html to the database? In terms of size, it will be over 8k per html page. The pages also have image files, so, to avoid the initial problem of upload it every new book, again I must save the images also in the database, right?

An example page for a book will be [like this](http://www.collok.com/read?bookId=1&chapterId=1)

Comment: If I got your question, you have an HTML page for each chapter of your book, right? And you want to show this specific page according to the book/chapter chosen. Right?

Comment: Right @Markon, this is exactly what I'm doing actually, getting each chapter from the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google app engine has a dedicated service for file uploads, it is called Blobstore.

You can write an administration page that let you upload file and publish them. You will need to use the database only to store meta data about each object: Book name, author, related image...

[Here's some documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview)

Comment: Thanks @Icfseth, I know the Blobstore, its intended to exaclty what you say: upload (big) files. This will be useful for upload images (for only 8k, I preffer to save the HTML text in a text field). So then, you recommend me to forget my actual method (static files) and save all in the database? Or you are telling me to upload the files (images and HTML files) and then make a process to extract it from database to a static file, mantaining my actual system for read static files only. Umm, sounds a good idea if was this.

Comment: I would personally go with the database approach. For now, you might not see the need for it, but later on, when may be you will want to implement some advanced features (rating, search by content, comments...) you will appreciate the fact that you went for it :) Whether you are using Python or PHP (I heard they have added support for it), you can easily integrate the HTML extracted in your templates.

Comment: Thanks @lcfseth, I think it too. I didn't do it before because I was trying to minimize the hits to the database (less hits, money you save), but I hope NDB will work well and serve most of the time from the cache.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a "poor man's" implementation, create a folder named 'books' in the top level of your application folder.  Inside of that, create one folder for each book, and inside each one of those, create one folder for each chapter.  This will give you a tree structure for your library.

Then, inside each book's folder, create an index.html file that acts as a cover page and table of contents.  It should have links to each chapter.  Inside each chapter's folder, create another index.html file that contains the HTML for that chapter.  All the images for that chapter go alongside the index.html file inside that folder, and all the links are relative, i.e.: href="picture.jpeg"

Change your app.yaml to serve up the 'books' folder as a Static Directory:

```
handlers:
- url: /books
  static_dir: books
```

If you never have to change the contents of the books, you can publish each book just once and deploy it.  The beauty of this is that no programming is required, beyond editing HTML and app.yaml.

Comment: this is almost exactly what I'm actually doing, which is the base of the problem: I need to "deploy" every time I want to upload a new chapter. Also, it is not possible to make the book's folder static, because then GAE cannot access its contents programatically to read the HTML files and include it on my templates (I've tested it). But yes, I have an structure /books/bookID/ and every chapter on each book folder. All the images are in the static folder /img/

Comment: Yes, you need to either deploy or upload a new chapter to the datastore/blobstore.  Both ways require someone to click a button.
Generate an index and deploy it too.

Comment: That is, generate an index of books and chapters and put it in your templates directory so you can read it on GAE.

Comment: The problem with deploy is that, for now, the unique user allowed to upload books it's me. But in the future, if I want to allow some other users to upload... the deploy system seems no very appropriated. That's why I will will work now in blobstore, to have all in the database. But for now, all is working very fast and very well (I've finished it today, with the deploy system)

Comment: You don't have to use the deploy feature. Just use a POST request (or the blobstore)...

Answer (score 1):

Why not upload your content using Google Drive and save your content in NDB. Reads are not expensive and the NDB datastore is very fast.

You can use the blobstore for images. Look at Google High Performance Image Serving, which makes use of the blobstore and get_serving_url from the Image API.

Comment: I will explore your recommendation, but I found more interesting, by now, the one from @Icfseth for make a kind of "own FTP", uploading files and saving internally to the right folder. In this way I save the use of datastore completely for static contents. Thanks.

Comment: Saving in the right folder???? You cannot save files in project folders. You have to read the blobstore for every item. Using Google Drive every author and book can have his own Drive folder, which makes it very easy to use for authors to apply new chapters and changes. In this way Google Drive acts as a book CMS.

Comment: You are right, it's impossible to save files to GAE, I forgot it. Was a good idea, eh? ;) What a pity! But then, I think it's better to use only blobs, if the NDB cache works well, only one read will be done for a especific chapter. I'm not much convinced with the use of Google Drive. Authors cannot publish by themselves, only I can do it. I will decide it after some tests. Thanks in any case.

Comment: I think I will get the database approach, like lcfseth told. Depend exclusively on Google Drive is a new point of dependency to add to the system (database and Google Drive), so it's better to use only that to what I'm bound to use (database).

Comment: Why use a blobproperty. You have text fields, like TextProperty ( Unicode string; unlimited length, not indexed) to store text and HTML. I use this for my Jinja CMS (not published). And what I mean with the drive CMS: Authors maintain there content in Drive. You get there latest content, store it in NDB and publish it. Using Google drive and docs you also get versioning for free.

Comment: TextProperty for HTML, but for the images (every chapter has some images) I will need blob. For the versioning, it is interesting, but in this case I don't need versioning, the book is only one and, once published, must not change except for typos.

Comment: For images (see my answer above), you have to use Google High Performance Image Serving. It is not only fast, but you do not have to serve the images youself (no CPU time!), Google will take care.

Answer (score 1):

If you structure your ndb entities right, the overhead will be very minimal.

Basically, just always do key-based reads.

Let's say you have:

```
def Template (ndb.model):
   data = ndb.TextProperty()
```

Then you can do reads like:

```
key = ndb.Key(Template, 'bookname.html')
data = key.get().data
```

ndb will automatically memcache these reads. So until memcache evicts them, they will be very fast and completely free.

The real thing to consider is size - ndb entities are limited to (IIRC) 1MB. If all your templates will be smaller than that, then you're good. If they're bigger, I'd suggest using the Blob Store. You'll still want to use ndb to store references to the Blob Store, though :)

Comment: Thanks @Murph, for confirming my suspicions about NDB. One thing: `data = key.get().data()` why the last data()? It's not enought with only `data = key.get()`?

Comment: Woops, that should just be key.get().data. key.get() returns the whole entity, then .data gets the property named 'data' from it.